# Reported speech (Would vs Would have)

Tags: reported-speech

For the sentence -

> The rock star asked me, "Would you sing the song with me?

Would the reported speech be -

(a) The rock star asked me if I would sing the song with him.

OR

(b) The rock star asked me if I would have sung the song with him.

Comment: Which one do you think is the correct answer?  What is confusing you?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is a.

You can only backshift those modals which have a past form (even when that past form can also be used independently): *will*-> *would*, *can*-> *could*, and for some speakers *shall*->*should* and *may*->*might*.

The other modals (including *would*) don't have corresponding past forms, and aren't changed when backshifting.

So your b)  corresponds to the direct question "Would you have sung the song with me?" which is a counterfactual question: "If (some unspecified condition, which didn't happen), would you have sung the song with me?"

In *some* contexts, *would have* could be a backshifted form of *will have*, eg "He asked me if I would have finished the book by the time he arrived", but that doesn't make much sense in your examplee.

Answer (score 0):

If it was a polite request - "Would you [like to] sing with me?" - the reported version would be *He asked me if I would sing with him.*

If it was a conditional - "Would you sing with me if you didn't have a sore throat/had had more time to practise/...etc?" you could use *He asked me if I would have sung with him if I hadn't had a sore throat/...etc.*